# How to Autostart an Android Application like whatsapp?

Tags: android, autostart, whatsapp

How I autostart my app on android like whatsapp. Application must start when system restart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to write  a service, it will read internet data. To start it on boot write broadcast receiver that will  execute on BOOT_COMPLETED or ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE. Your GUI app should comunicate with service using AIDL interface - if service will run in the same process as application, then no AIDL should be required.